# Ubuntu Lost /dev/log symlink?

Tags: symbolic-link

I'm experience a problem in Ubuntu. I guess since last update, I've lost the `/dev/log` symlink.

something like:

```
/dev/log -> /run/systemd/journal/dev-log=
```

How can i recreate it?

For example:

```
update-grub --> logger: socket /dev/log: No such file or directory logger: socket /dev/log: No such file or directory
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Since the `/dev` file system is created and populated at boot, the easiest way to restore `/dev/log` is to reboot the system in question.

Alternatively, if it was indeed a symbolic link, you know its former target and the target still exists, you can recreate it with:

```
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/journal/dev-log /dev/log
```

Comment: ls /dev/log
ls: cannot access '/dev/log': Too many levels of symbolic links , after this, i've created the symlink...it seems ok now! thanks David!